# Show that any enumerable set is either finite or equinumerous with the natural numbers.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I really do not know how to show this in any sound manner. For any enumerable set **A** there exists a surjective function f from **N** to **A**.

I then proceeded by arguing that if f is an injection it is a bijection and **A** would be infinite. Otherwise if f is not an injection f^-1 would still be total and therefore for every a ∈ **A** there exists a nonempty set **M**_a ⊂ **N** with f(m) = a for all m ∈ **M**_a. If we now construct a function g which assisgns to every a the smallest m ∈ **M**_a, then g is a bijection. Because g is a function mapping **A** to a subset of **N**, **A** would be finite.

But this does not hold because there are infinite subsets of **N**.
If anybody could tell me how to prove this id be very gratefull.

EDIT: enumerbility is defined as there being a surjective function from **N** to **A**

Comment: How do you define enumerability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructing bijection $f$ from $A$ to $N_A\subseteq\mathbb N$ can certainly serve as a starting point. Now either $N_A$ is bounded  or it isn't.

If it has there's an $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $j\in N_A\Rightarrow j<n$. This means that $N_A$ is finite (it's no larger than $n$).

If it hasn't we construct an surjection from $N_A$ to $\mathbb N$ which would show that $|N_A| \ge|\mathbb N|$ and since $N_A\subseteq\mathbb N$ it would prove that $N_A$ is equinumerous to $\mathbb N$. Now define $G_n = \{x\in N_A: x < n\}$, now $g(n) = |G_n|$ is such a mapping.

The latest claim can be shown by induction. Since $g(0)=0$ we have that $0$ is part of the range of $g$. And if $j$ is in the range, that is there's an $n$ such that $j = g(n)$ then we can just take the minimum of $N_A\setminus G_N$ to find a $m$ such that $g(m) = j+1$.

Now we have $f:A\to N_A$ bijectively and $g:N_A\to \mathbb N$ bijectively, this means that $g\circ f: A\to\mathbb N$ bijectively which means that $A$ and $\mathbb N$ are equinumerous.

Comment: How can $N_A$ does not have the Archimedian property? Is not the Archimedian property is satisfied for any real number?

Comment: I want to show that every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is either finite or countable .... is this the same proof that you mentioned above in your answer?

Comment: In the fourth line from below why you said that $g(n) = |G_n|$ is the required map?

Comment: @Intuition I meant that either it's bounded or not. The proof starts there and if it's bounded it is proven to be finite and if it's not bounded it's proven to be equinumerous to $\mathbb N$. The role of $g(n)$ is to map from $N_A$ to $\mathbb N$, we already assume that we have a bijection from $A$ to $N_A$ which mean that $g\circ f$ is a bijection from $A$ to $\mathbb N$.